# Google Analytics with HTTPS protocol with mod_pagespeed

Tags: google-analytics, mod-pagespeed

I've used the following information to get mod_pagespeed to inject the GA scripts into my pages:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-insert-ga

Unfortunately we have a reverse proxy setup where the browser requests the page over HTTPS but the server injects the content as HTTP.

Here is the Chrome browser error:

> [blocked] The page at 'https://***' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran
>   insecure content from 'http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js': this
>   content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

I need this module to use the correct protocol when injecting the script i.e. https:// www.google-analytics.com/ga.js (*Sorry for the broken URL I can't post more than 2 links*)

Answer (score 0):

We don't have an answer yet, but you can track progress of this bug here: https://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/issues/detail?id=877

Answer (score 0):

You are going to run into this issue a lot.  Try fixing the proxy/server so it correctly identifies the end-user connection as SSL.  Most Load Balancers inject a header and have an apache mod to read the header for you.